# How can I make my PATH more succinct in ZSH?

Tags: python, anaconda, zsh

I am using ZSH. I was having trouble running the Anaconda package manager commands in my terminal. I found that I could add the bin to my PATH using this code:

```
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

That worked. All of the Anaconda and associated commands work and it left me with this PATH:

```
/Users/USER/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

But the PATH variable would reset each time I closed the terminal window. After some research, I figured out how modify my .zshrc to make it permanent. I simply pasted this into my .zshrc:

```
export PATH=/Users/USER/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

All the commands work and are permanent, but aren't I setting myself up for failure down the road? Everything in the PATH, minus the "/Users/USER/anaconda3/bin" were set automatically. What happens when I update Python, for example? How can I include the "USER/anaconda3/bin" portion of my PATH in my .zshrc without being so explicit?

Comment: The first command you tried, `export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`, should also work from your `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) concern is not `zsh` specific. You could organize things differently.

For example, you could decide to add a directory `$HOME/bin/` early in your `PATH` and put inside that `$HOME/bin/` symbolic links to the [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) (or [scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script)) that *you* want to use. BTW, I recommend to have a short `PATH` (containing some  `$HOME/bin/` etc...) since it is more efficient and less messy to understand.

> What happens when I update Python, for example?

Let's suppose that Python is installed in your system in  `/usr/bin/python` (and that you use some Linux distribution -or some other Unix- with a good [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) dealing with that;on MacOSX consider [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)). When that file `/usr/bin/python` is updated, any future [exec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) of it (e.g. by some shell) will use the new version. Read carefully [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

If ou have several Python-s and the one you want to use is under `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` and you upgraded it to some Python 3.7 installed under `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin` you would need to change your `PATH`.

If you followed my suggestion, you would (for example) just have a symlink from `$HOME/bin/python` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python` and you would upgrade that symlink when installing Python3.7 using for example:

```
# remove the old symlink
rm -v $HOME/bin/python
# add the new one
ln -sv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python \
   $HOME/bin/python
```

In all cases, you are responsible of having a good enough `PATH` (and preferably a short one).